# How do I solve problem with useRef of NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, use-ref, model-viewer

I'm making a SSG page using Nextjs.
I imported model-viewer by write a  tag not  of Next.js.
And I want to activate AR automatically when user enter this page.
So I activateAR() in useEffect() using useRef
but an error happens cause of value 'null' of useRef.

1. Using  of 'next/link', first error -> refresh? it works.
2. Using  or type URL directly on the browser, it works without error. Although null is printed on console window at first.

Please shed light on my developer road.

oh this page is SSG with dynamic routing.

```
const viewer = useRef<any>(null);

useEffect(()=>{
function loadArFile() {
 viewer.current?.activateAR();
}

 viewer && loadArFile();
}
,[])

<Head>
        <title>argateway</title>
        <script
          type="module"
          src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"
        />
</Head>

<model-viewer
        ref={viewer} />
```